# Run Visual Studio unit tests in a specific folder from command line

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, vstest

I am aiming to find a way to run the tests contained in a group of assemblies from command line.

The tests have been built using Visual Studio Testing Framework and the assemblies are all located in the same folder.

What I want to extract are the tests results (especially the list of failed ones) and possibly the code coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the vstest.console.exe program, it is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155796.aspx
It outputs the results to the console, which you can pipe to a file if you like. It can also log the output to a trx test file, which can be opened in Visual Studio and viewed there.

Use it as:
vstest.console  file1.test.dll  file2.test.dll  /logger:trx  > testresults.txt

It does not accept wildcards for the filenames, but you can wrap it in a powershellscript to achieve that, if you like.

If you add the  /EnableCodeCoverage option, you also get a .coverage file, which you also can open up in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a script to retrieve all the Tests assemblies names and using them as parameters for vstest.

It's a pity there's no way to convert the Code Coverage output to a readable format such as xml using VS tools . Anyway I found some third party tools and I will give them a chance